# push from bare git repository

Tags: git, git-bare

I am trying to use a bare git repo as a bridge between my working repo and the origin

```
origin ----- bare repo ----- working repo
```

I can go into the working repo and push and pull from the bare repo. But I also need to go into the bare repo and push and pull form the origin, is that possible?

**EDIT**

What I've tried so far...

To create the bare repo

```
mkdir bare_repo
cd bare_repo
git init --bare
git remote add origin path_to_origin
git fetch origin
```

To create the working repo

```
git clone path_to_bare
```

I get a warning: "remote HEAD refers to nonexistant ref, unable to checkout", but it still creates the working repo

```
git pull origin master
```

I get an error: "Couldnt find remote ref master"

**UPDATE**

Turns out I had a write permissions issue, and so I couldn't push from the working repo to the bare repo. So I general I need to check permissions for all my repo locations before asking questions... Now everything is working...

One things is, if someone else pushes a commit to the origin, I will need to fetch that commit from my bare repo and update the branch on my bare repo. The fetch is simple enough

```
# in bare repo
git fetch origin master
```

but I dont know the best way to update the branch. I cant pull because there is no working directory. I can get the hash of the new commit using

```
git ls-remote
```

and then manually point the branch to it with

```
git branch -f master <hash>
```

But it seems like there would be a better way.

But I think that should be a separate question.

Comment: What's the purpose of the bare repo?

Comment: Its a long story and I don't think its relevant. The question is, can git do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything? For a push or pull operation, you don't need a working directory, so there shouldn't be any difference between the bare repo and your working repo in this case.

Comment: @chepner OK I've added what I've tried so far to my question

Comment: Unless `bare_repo` is inside another repository, that `git remote` command shouldn't even work.

Comment: My bad, I forgot the "git init --bare" line

Comment: @chuck1 I know you said it's a long story, but it probably is relevant. There's probably a better way to solve whatever you're solving with the middle bare repo. Perhaps with an ssh tunnel?

Comment: @Schwern I agree with you that there is probably a better solution to my underlying issue. But this is a question about what git is capable of and how to use it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can clone the original repo as a bare repo with: `git clone --bare <repo url>`

Comment: Tried this. When I try to push a new commit from the working repo to the bare repo, I get: "remote unpack failed: unable to create temporary object directory"

Comment: Actually this does work, see my update. You can also create an empty bare repo and add the remote manually though.